# how do i provide an overload to take a vector argument?

Tags: c++, vector

how do i  provide an overload to take a vector argument?

```
void res(uint8_t* buffer, int len)
{
std::vector<uint8_t> buf( buffer, buffer + len ); 
// here i want to pass buf as uint8_t* to onther func
pack((uint8_t*)buf, len));// error 
}

IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "std::vector<uint8_t, std::allocator<uint8_t>>" to "uint8_t *"
```

Comment: In what way is overloading involved in this??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pass the address of the first element.

```
pack(&buf[0], len);
```

Comment: When doing this, keep in mind that the vector can be reallocated, and the first element might not be located at the same address the second time you access the pointer.

Comment: And the reason for the compiler error: The vector itself (nor a pointer to it) isn't the pointer to the data held by this vector. The type of `buf` is `std::vector<uint8_t>` and not `uint8_t*`.

Comment: @MixedCoder: This is guaranteed by the standard. Vectors hold its data in a contiguous chunk of memory and the pointer to the first element is the pointer to this chunk.

Comment: @phlipsy -but it'll work only for implementations that store vector elements contiguously right?

Comment: @MixedCoder: As far as I know (I can't cite any location in current C++ standard) it's guaranteed. Otherwise your standard library isn't, well, standard... Besides that: It's the whole thing about vectors. They are supposed to be a substitution for C-like arrays.